# how to inject environmental variables in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, hudson

Jenkins complaining abt the commands like chmod, rm, mv not found. SO I need to add path=/bin:/usr/bin in the environmental variables. How can I inject those path so that it won't have problem finding those commands?

Thanks for help !!

Comment: I'm pretty surprised that /bin and /usr/bin aren't on the PATH to the JVM - I've never had to define those in order to use common commands. Are the errors you're seeing happening from an "Execute shell" build step or in some other context?

Comment: yes these are the problem seen when I have the commands like chmod, rm, mv etc on the "Execute Shell" box in Jenkins. I have to add "setenv PATH /usr/bin:/bin:$PATH" manually in each and every Job Configuration and I tried changing it on manage node on manage jenkins but didn't take it. I see it is placed there but doesn't show up in the injected env variables.

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer, to set env variables - go to Manage Jenkins->Configure System (address host:port/configure) - there's a section Global Properties and a checkbox called Environment Variables - check it and you can define variables there which will be set when jobs run.